# Returning Access database values using VBA / SQL

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still getting used to working with SQL & Access with VBA.

I'm looking to run a query which will return just AccountNumber & BorrowerName from our Access database. When I run 'SELECT AccountNumber, BorrowerName', it only returns the AccountNumbers and without the heading in column A. Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

```
    'runs an sql query
Sub RunQueryOnAccess()

    Dim conn As New Connection, rec As New Recordset
    Dim DBPATH, PRVD, connString, query As String

    'Declaring fully qualified name of database. Change it with your database's location and name.
    DBPATH = "Z:\Danny Tool Test Folder\Database\MasterFile_February2021.accdb"

    'This is the connection provider. Remember this for your interview.
    PRVD = "Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;"

    'This is the connection string that you will require when opening the the connection.
    connString = "Provider=" & PRVD & "Data Source=" & DBPATH

    'opening the connection
    conn.Open connString

    'the query I want to run on the database.
    query = "SELECT Accountnumber, BorrowerName from CaseManagers;"

    
    'running the query on the open connection. It will get all the data in the rec object.
    rec.Open query, conn

    'clearing the content of the cells
    Cells.ClearContents

    'getting data from the recordset if any and printing it in column A of excel sheet.
    If (rec.RecordCount <> 0) Then
        Do While Not rec.EOF
            Range("A" & Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).Value2 = _
            rec.Fields(1).value
            rec.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    
    'closing the connections
    rec.Close
    conn.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: `Fields` are zero-based, so do `rec.Fields(0).value` instead.

Comment: Is it Accountnumber or Accountnumbers?

Comment: Thanks, this resolves the error message but it still only returns 1 column when I run SELECT *. @BrianMStafford

Comment: Your code only reads one field...

Comment: FYI `RecordCount` is not a very reliable way to determine if you got anything returned: you can just test `rec.EOF` right after `Open` for that.